# Flexible Conjugate Residual

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method, preconditioning, conjugate-gradient

If we want to use variable preconditioning in Conjugate Gradient, we can replace the  Fletcher–Reeves by the Polak–Ribière formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_flexible_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method). Is there a similar formulation when the update is performed as in the Conjugate Residual https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_residual_method ? The application I have in mind is minimizing
$$
\frac12 \|Ax-b\|_2^2+\lambda \|x\|_1
$$
when $A$ is symmetric but not necessarily positive definite (in the spd case, one could get away with using flexible conjugate gradient here).